# Second order ODE with rational function coefficient without first derivative term

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, frobenius-method

I am trying to find the solution for below ODE for $y(x)$:
$$y''+f(x)y=0$$
where $f(x)=\frac{A_4x^4+A_3x^3+A_2x^2+A_1x+A_0}{x^2(B_2x^2+B_1x+B_0)}$. In this equation $A_4, A_3, A_2, A_1, A_0, B_2, B_1, B_0$ are constants.
I tried to use Frobenius method but I couldn't solve it. I also checked "Handbook of Exact Solutions for Ordinary Differential Equations", couldn't find anything useful.

I really appreciate your help Let me know if you need more information. Thanks

Comment: The coefficient $f(x)$ you define is *not* a polynomial, rather it is a rational function of $x$ of a specific form. So maybe change the title... also is there some reason why this specific form is of interest? That is, how does this diffEQ arise?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, You are absolutely right about the title. I tried to solve a complex PDE for the diffusion equation in a certain geometry and this is the outcome of several transformations.

Comment: I (and perhaps others) would be interested if some details about the "certain geometry" were given in the question, also if "the diffusion equation" PDE were explained a bit.

Comment: Sure, I will add some details.